# Tracking Down Memory Leaks With Memory Analyser - Multiples of Activities With Dollar Signs

Tags: android, memory, duplicates, analysis

I'm getting the following output when I look at the histogram for the heap dump in the eclipse memory analyser tool. There are a lot of repeats of activities and views with a dollar sign and a number after it (e.g. SplashScreenActivity$2). Can anyone tell me what these duplicates with dollar signs are?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dollar signs are Anonymous classes like `new OnClickListener() {...}`

---

If you access private members from your inner class, accessor methods are created, they should have dollar signs too.

Comment: So those activities with dollar signs after them are leaking anonymous classes (e.g. so SplashScreenActivity$2 means that my SplashScreenActivity is leaking class called 2)?

Comment: I'm not sure about leaking, I do not know the tool for memory analysis. But if it says SplashScreeActivity$2, it means some anonymous class created in SplashScreenActivity that got name 2.